# Dropping Columns with specific strings in a specific row using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

So right now I have a huge census data set that I'm trying to clean up via Pandas. As it stands, I have a bunch of columns measuring "Statistical Significance" which contain either a null value or and '*'. The "Statistical Significance" phrase is located not in the column name, but the first row of the column as a description row.
There are over 2000 of them, and I just want to drop them all using Python (I'll be doing most of the actual data analysis in R). 
After some tweaking, I got this to successfully output a new CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/ht1.csv')
def drop(data):
    df2 = []
    for x in data:
        if  "Significance" in data.loc[0,x]:
            data.drop(x, axis = 1, inplace=True)
            return data
ndf = drop(df)
ndf.to_csv('~/Desktop/ht2.csv')
```

However, there's an issue with the columns actually dropping (as in, they don't... at all). I'm at my wits end trying to use my relatively limited coding knowledge and frustratingly obtuse internet articles to solve the issue.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to drop the rows containing the word or the column itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two flaws in your code:

1. Your `return` is carried out in the `if` block, so you return that
   data after dropping the first column, further columns with
   'Significance' are left in the dataframe.
2. Dropping columns inplace while you iterate over the data leads to
   confusion.

This works:

```
def drop(data):
    cols = []
    for x in data:
        if  "Significance" in data.loc[0,x]:
            cols.append(x)
    data.drop(cols, axis = 1, inplace=True)
    return data
```

A **shorter and more elegant** way to achieve what you want is

```
newdf = df.loc[:,~df.iloc[0].str.contains('Significance')]
```